# MarkLogic taskserver status

Tags: marklogic

We have dedicated D-node and E-node groups in the production config. and I am trying to gather the request status of the task server across all the hosts in the D-node group. I am using *xdmp:server-status(host_id,server_id)* where *host_id* is the ID of one of our six hosts belonging to the D-node group, and the *server_id* is the id of the taskserver for the D-node group. The query runs just fine but I have confusions about some elements in the output (see below).

1. What is the difference between the *threads* and *max_threads* elements? I looked up the MarkLogic API for *xdmp:server-status()* and looks like they have put the same description for both these elements which is obviously wrong.
2. Does the sum of request_status elements represents the number of tasks running? That's probably intuitive but just wanted to confirm.

   ```
   <server-status xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/status/server">
     <server-id>11927597993558616659</server-id>
     <host-id>10652389071003024571</host-id>
     <server-kind>task-server</server-kind>
     <enabled>true</enabled>
     <threads>9</threads>
     <max-threads>16</max-threads>
     <max-time-limit>3600</max-time-limit>
     <default-time-limit>600</default-time-limit>
     <current-time>2015-08-26T04:06:41.622879-04:00</current-time>
     <request-statuses>
       <request-status>
       <request-id>17847109729564550394</request-id>
       <server-id>11927597993558616659</server-id>
       <host-id>10652389071003024571</host-id>
       <transaction-id>11386673421668364533</transaction-id>
       <canceled>false</canceled>
       <modules>16882056828749629778</modules>
       <database>13691199455930504749</database>
       <root>/</root>
       <request-kind>invoke</request-kind>
       <request-text>/MarkLogic/cpf/triggers/on-state-enter.xqy</request-text>
       <update>false</update>
       <start-time>2015-08-26T04:06:41.621354-04:00</start-time>
       <time-limit>600</time-limit>
       <max-time-limit>3600</max-time-limit>
       <user>15525372533614500271</user>
       <trigger-depth>0</trigger-depth>
       <expanded-tree-cache-hits>0</expanded-tree-cache-hits>
       <expanded-tree-cache-misses>0</expanded-tree-cache-misses>
       <request-state>running</request-state>
       <profiling-allowed>true</profiling-allowed>
       <profiling-enabled>false</profiling-enabled>
       <debugging-allowed>true</debugging-allowed>
       <debugging-status>detached</debugging-status>
       <retry-count>0</retry-count>
     </request-status>
     <request-status>
       <request-id>8474714682726605430</request-id>
       <server-id>11927597993558616659</server-id>
       <host-id>10652389071003024571</host-id>
       <transaction-id>8554209989266201299</transaction-id>
       <canceled>false</canceled>
       <modules>16882056828749629778</modules>
       <database>13691199455930504749</database>
       <root>/</root>
       <request-kind>invoke</request-kind>
       <request-text>/MarkLogic/cpf/triggers/on-state-enter.xqy</request-text>
       <update>true</update>
       <start-time>2015-08-26T04:06:41.483786-04:00</start-time>
       <time-limit>600</time-limit>
       <max-time-limit>3600</max-time-limit>
       <user>15525372533614500271</user>
       <trigger-depth>0</trigger-depth>
       <expanded-tree-cache-hits>20</expanded-tree-cache-hits>
       <expanded-tree-cache-misses>0</expanded-tree-cache-misses>
       <request-state>running</request-state>
       <profiling-allowed>true</profiling-allowed>
       <profiling-enabled>false</profiling-enabled>
       <debugging-allowed>true</debugging-allowed>
       <debugging-status>detached</debugging-status>
       <retry-count>0</retry-count>
     </request-status>
     <request-status>
       <request-id>6530741740134403011</request-id>
       <server-id>11927597993558616659</server-id>
       <host-id>10652389071003024571</host-id>
       <transaction-id>14792921325069589956</transaction-id>
       <canceled>false</canceled>
       <modules>16882056828749629778</modules>
       <database>13691199455930504749</database>
       <root>/</root>
       <request-kind>invoke</request-kind>
       <request-text>/MarkLogic/cpf/triggers/on-state-enter.xqy</request-text>
       <update>true</update>
       <start-time>2015-08-26T04:06:41.52227-04:00</start-time>
       <time-limit>600</time-limit>
       <max-time-limit>3600</max-time-limit>
       <user>15525372533614500271</user>
       <trigger-depth>0</trigger-depth>
       <expanded-tree-cache-hits>20</expanded-tree-cache-hits>
       <expanded-tree-cache-misses>0</expanded-tree-cache-misses>
       <request-state>running</request-state>
       <profiling-allowed>true</profiling-allowed>
       <profiling-enabled>false</profiling-enabled>
       <debugging-allowed>true</debugging-allowed>
       <debugging-status>detached</debugging-status>
       <retry-count>0</retry-count>
     </request-status>
     <request-status>
       <request-id>9441948619847315123</request-id>
       <server-id>11927597993558616659</server-id>
       <host-id>10652389071003024571</host-id>
       <transaction-id>13501074757179797206</transaction-id>
       <canceled>false</canceled>
       <modules>16882056828749629778</modules>
       <database>13691199455930504749</database>
       <root>/</root>
       <request-kind>invoke</request-kind>
       <request-text>/MarkLogic/cpf/triggers/on-status-enter.xqy</request-text>
       <update>false</update>
       <start-time>2015-08-26T04:06:41.594876-04:00</start-time>
       <time-limit>600</time-limit>
       <max-time-limit>3600</max-time-limit>
       <user>15525372533614500271</user>
       <trigger-depth>0</trigger-depth>
       <expanded-tree-cache-hits>0</expanded-tree-cache-hits>
       <expanded-tree-cache-misses>0</expanded-tree-cache-misses>
       <request-state>running</request-state>
       <profiling-allowed>true</profiling-allowed>
       <profiling-enabled>false</profiling-enabled>
       <debugging-allowed>true</debugging-allowed>
       <debugging-status>detached</debugging-status>
       <retry-count>0</retry-count>
     </request-status>
     <request-status>
       <request-id>3267724788720707644</request-id>
       <server-id>11927597993558616659</server-id>
       <host-id>10652389071003024571</host-id>
       <transaction-id>16009199203479096620</transaction-id>
       <canceled>false</canceled>
       <modules>16882056828749629778</modules>
       <database>13691199455930504749</database>
       <root>/</root>
       <request-kind>invoke</request-kind>
       <request-text>/MarkLogic/cpf/triggers/on-state-enter.xqy</request-text>
       <update>true</update>
       <start-time>2015-08-26T04:06:41.483616-04:00</start-time>
       <time-limit>600</time-limit>
       <max-time-limit>3600</max-time-limit>
       <user>13094335114653925163</user>
       <trigger-depth>0</trigger-depth>
       <expanded-tree-cache-hits>20</expanded-tree-cache-hits>
       <expanded-tree-cache-misses>0</expanded-tree-cache-misses>
       <request-state>running</request-state>
       <profiling-allowed>true</profiling-allowed>
       <profiling-enabled>false</profiling-enabled>
       <debugging-allowed>true</debugging-allowed>
       <debugging-status>detached</debugging-status>
       <retry-count>0</retry-count>
     </request-status>
   </request-statuses>
   <request-rate>16.11519</request-rate>
   <queue-size>0</queue-size>
   <queue-limit>100000</queue-limit>
   <expanded-tree-cache-hits>241396964</expanded-tree-cache-hits>
   <expanded-tree-cache-misses>65339949</expanded-tree-cache-misses>
   <expanded-tree-cache-hit-rate>161.5713</expanded-tree-cache-hit-rate>
   <expanded-tree-cache-miss-rate>8.095861</expanded-tree-cache-miss-rate>
   <fs-program-cache-hits>26819890</fs-program-cache-hits>
   <fs-program-cache-misses>26819890</fs-program-cache-misses>
   <db-program-cache-hits>3632389</db-program-cache-hits>
   <db-program-cache-misses>3632389</db-program-cache-misses>
   <fs-main-module-seq-cache-hits>4694</fs-main-module-seq-cache-hits>
   <fs-main-module-seq-cache-misses>4694</fs-main-module-seq-cache-misses>
   <db-main-module-seq-cache-hits>15144</db-main-module-seq-cache-hits>
   <db-main-module-seq-cache-misses>15144</db-main-module-seq-cache-misses>
   <fs-lib-module-cache-hits>1102986</fs-lib-module-cache-hits>
   <fs-lib-module-cache-misses>1102986</fs-lib-module-cache-misses>
   <db-lib-module-cache-hits>14221</db-lib-module-cache-hits>
   <db-lib-module-cache-misses>14221</db-lib-module-cache-misses>
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the docs are wrong, I will file a bug on that, they mean what you probably think.  max-threads is the max number of threads that can run, threads is the current number of 'running' threads. The sum of request-status should (generally) match threads.  Since threads are in a 'pool' there are periods where the sums dont match exactly.

You can try this out for a simple test.

```
for $i in 1 to 1000 return 
xdmp:spawn-function( function () { xdmp:sleep(10000) } )
```

It should return immediately filling the queue with 1000 tasks.

Then run this occasionally

```
xdmp:server-status(xdmp:host(),xdmp:server("TaskServer")) ! (./*:threads,count(./*:request-statuses/*:request-status))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @DALDEI. I have consistently seen that the sum of request-status comes less than the threads. I am not sure I fully understand how this is explained by the fact that the threads are pooled. Apologies if I am missing something obvious!

Comment: max_threads just means there will be a certain number of parallel running worker threads working to clear the task server queue, and that number cannot exceed max_threads. max_threads represents the thread pool size, the reservoir of reusable worker thread objects. threads tells how many are actually active..

Comment: Thanks. I just think the number of request_status elements should match with the value of the threads elements if they essentially represent the same information.